# How to run concurrent infinite jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jobs

I have multiple jobs (functions) that process data in my DB.
They should be run indefinitely and concurrently. I was wondering about the
best way to run them. Should I write a bash file that starts `node somejob.js` for each job or should I use node workers from a JavaScript file, or some other method altogether?

Comment: This question needs more details, please complete it with more details about what the functions actually do in order to get proper answers

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know the best way to do such a job, but I have recently worked on a similar problem.
Since this is a broad question, but for illustration, I will give you an example of a mailing service.

I was asked to make a mailing service which can be used by other services,
to queue non similar raw emails with custom templates until it is sent.

A program (or worker) which I named `dispatcher` runs indefinitely, and checks for queued email
in DB. Fetched atmost `n` queued email (our email service has some threshold). 
and send them concurrently, wait for `some` seconds and do that again.

To run dispatcher indefinitely I have used [`async.forever`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#forever).

To run concurrent jobs, I have used [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map).

It seems you can do this in JS itself instead of using bash file (for some cron stuff). You can find lot of other useful methods here [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/)

Comment: Does async execute the code in separate threads? (i.e. can it use multiple cores)?

Comment: Yes, you can see it here: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map. But I don't know the internal working, they also have async.parallel.

Comment: The source code says it only uses a single thread:
 * **Note:** `parallel` is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about
 * parallel execution of code.  If your tasks do not use any timers or perform
 * any I/O, they will actually be executed in series.  Any synchronous setup
 * sections for each task will happen one after the other.  JavaScript remains
 * single-threaded.